# Get particular object from an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

My array object contains multiple objects. How to get the particular object from an array. My array(_arrSection) is

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7fa53a69d380>(  //////_arrSection
<__NSArrayI 0x7fa53c8422e0>(
29077
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x7fa53a531930>(
32102.38,
67419.6,
25913.85,
247547.66,
52869.06
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x7fa53a56f560>(
43173,
197220.19,
108825
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x7fa53a530150>(
199476.25,
814590.87
)
)
```

Now i want to get only below values

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7fa53a56f560>(
43173,
197220.19,
108825
)
```

Comment: can you not just go `array[index]` where `index` is the one you want? which will give you the array of values

Comment: is it like this  [_arrSections objectAtIndex:getIndexSection];

Comment: yes, `_arrSections[getIndexSection]` is short hand for your version

Comment: @ Fonix Thank you.  Now i want to replace the values in to the same index of array (_arrSection).

Comment: @elavarasan just do this _arrSections [buffer replaceObjectAtIndex:getIndexSection withObject:arrTemp];

Comment: I got it [_arrSection replaceObjectAtIndex:getIndexSection withObject:tempArray];

Comment: @elavarasan by mistake i have written _arrSections [buffer replaceObjectAtIndex:getIndexSection withObject:arrTemp]; replace this code by [_arrSections replaceObjectAtIndex:getIndexSection withObject:arrTemp];

Comment: @Hardik Shekhat got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
NSArray *tempArray = [yourArray objectAtIndex:index]; 
NSLog(@"Print Temp Array %@",tempArray);
```

**Update**

```
Use for replace value 
[_arrSection replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@"Replace Value Set Here"];
```

after doing print value .. you will get same like you want . Hope you will get success .. thanks :)

Comment: i got it but Now i want to replace the values in to the same index of array (_arrSection)

Answer (score 0):

you can use objectAtIndex property of NSArray. Use index number to get the object from NSArray.

like 
NSArray *getArray = [_arrSection objectAtIndex:2];

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[sectionArray addObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@(29077), nil]];
[sectionArray addObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@(32102.38),@(67419.6),@(25913.85),@(247547.66),@(52869.06), nil]];
[sectionArray addObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@(43173),@(197220.19),@(108825), nil]];
[sectionArray addObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@(199476.25),@(814590.87), nil]];

int sectionIndex = 2;
NSArray *rowArray = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:sectionIndex];//
NSLog(@"rowArray:%@",rowArray);

int rowIndex = 1;
NSNumber *value = [rowArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex];//rowIndex
NSLog(@"rowIndex value:%@",value);
```

Comment: Why use this long-hand version of the syntax?

Comment: many a time people down vote on a question because of it's simplicity. but simplicity does not worth of down vote, should the answer of simplicity. simple question means he/she is beginner. that my answer is more details.

Comment: Why are you talking about downvoting when I was interested in why you are promoting a longer, more cumbersome, syntax when a much more convenient syntax has been in use for several years?